# Is it possible to turn on Android Phone from Powered off status?

Tags: android, mobile

I am doing just one my college project, want to turn on phone from off status searched so many but not found any solution.

Comment: When the phone is in a fully powered off state, the user has to turn on the phone using the power button.

Answer (score 3):

This question is more hardware related, all the codes we make, only work if the phone is in 'on state'.

If you really want to achieve something like that, then i think you will have the change the parts of hardware manually, which is pretty difficult... you will have to some how link the power on mechanism of the phone to a microprocessor integrated circuit[ the linking medium is mandatory to be wireless ], which indirectly means that even if your phone is in off-state, some part of it will always be on, which could keep on consuming some battery.

Comment: I think this is not true because alarm work on most mobile phone even if the mobile is turned off, How alarm works?